# Is it possible to get the real and the imaginary value of my results in Abaqus by extracting the history output data using a python script?

Tags: python, abaqus

I am performing a steady state dynamics step in Abaqus und therefore have complex results. Since I need the values of a couple of hundred nodes I am trying to get these results using a python script. I took this script from the documentary and adapted it for my model, which works, but I only get the real values. Is there a way to extract the real values as well as the imaginary values?

```
from odbAccess import *

odb = openOdb(path='viewer_tutorial.odb')
step2 = odb.steps['Step-2']
region = step2.historyRegions['Node PART-1-1.1000']
u2Data = region.historyOutputs['U2'].data
dispFile = open('disp.dat','w')
for time, u2Disp in u2Data:
    dispFile.write('%10.4E   %10.4E\n' % (time, u2Disp))
dispFile.close()
```

If anyone would know a solution to my problem, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, `conjugateData` is the answer for your problem. 
`u2Data_complex = region.historyOutputs['U2'].conjugateData`